# C# Reading Output From Batch file

Tags: c#

Please help me with this

```
Process myProcess = new Process();

ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(batchfilelocation);
myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;
myProcess.Start();

StreamReader myStreamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput;

// Read the standard output of the spawned process.
string concatenatedString = null;

concatenatedString += myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

listBox1.Text = listBox1.Text + concatenatedString;

myProcess.Close();
```

I need help with this What do i put for

`ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(batchfilelocation);`

Comment: batchfilelocation is a string that contains the path to the filename of the batch file you want to run.

Comment: Yes but how do i put it? like ("Path") ?

Comment: Batch files are not executable images, and you can't launch one as a process.  The process to start is `cmd.exe` with argument  `/c batchfilelocation`.  The other option is to ShellExecute the batch file, which treats it the same as if you double-clicked it in explorer (and launches cmd.exe anyway)